# Unable to send Xml request

Tags: python, django, xml, python-requests, python-responses

*Am having issue sending xml request in pthon because i don't know how to render python code in
xml. I have no idea how to render or navigate xml text like in example below or how to render python code in xml text before sending the python request.*

```
def start_xml_payment(request):
      if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormPaymentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
              payment  = form.save() 
              first_name = request.user.first_name
              last_name = request.user.last_name
              
              email = request.user.email
              serdate = datetime.datetime.now()
              ref = payment.ref
              amount = payment.amount 
              fees = payment.fees
              datejson_str = json.dumps({'created_at': serdate}, default=str)

              url = 'https://secure.powerpay.com/API/v6/'
              xml = '''  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                      <API3G>
                      <code>4332-9D7F-4E09-96D4-3D44E7A83EA3</Code>
                      <Transaction>
                      <PaymentAmount>{amount}</PaymentAmount >
                      <customerEmail>{email}</customerEmail>
                      </Transaction>
                      <Services>
                          <Service>
                            <ServiceDate>{datejson_str}</ServiceDate>
                          </Service>
                      </Services>
                      </API3G>
                    '''

              headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/xml'}
              response = requests.post(url, data=xml, headers=headers)
              response_data = response.json()
              TransToken = response_data["TransToken"]
              cashier_response = 'https://secure.powerpay.com/p.php?ID={TransToken}' 
              return  HttpResponseRedirect (cashier_response)
      else:
        form = FormPaymentForm(request.POST)
        return render(request, 'dpo/start_dpo_payment.html', {'form': form})
```

**Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><API3G><Result>000</Result><ResultExplanation>Transaction created</ResultExplanation><TransToken>803E06BC-CB80-4671-9F92-90326411ACFC</TransToken><TransRef>R39855046</TransRef></API3G>
```

*I want to navigate through this xml response and fetch TransToken*

```
TransToken = response_data["TransToken"]
```

*i want something like this*

```
cashier_response = 'https://secure.powerpay.com/p.php?ID={TransToken}'
```

****Issue 1****
*i have issue fetching the Transtoken because am unable to navigate through the xml response to get the transtoken and merge the transtoken to my url.*

**I need help in navigating xml text like example above**

**Issue 2**
*How do I render data from the form into the xml text before sending the post request.
since xml is always commeneted with """ xml code """ in python file the normal python code will not always work when i try to render my python code in xml .
i tried using the normal python {} like {amount} in rendering the amount or {ref} in rendering ref but it didnt work.*

*I need help to fix this issue*

Answer (score 0):

> I want to navigate through this xml response and fetch TransToken

See below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><API3G><Result>000</Result>
        <ResultExplanation>Transaction created</ResultExplanation>
        <TransToken>803E06BC-CB80-4671-9F92-90326411ACFC</TransToken>
        <TransRef>R39855046</TransRef>
    </API3G>
'''

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
print(root.find('.//TransToken').text)
```

output

```
803E06BC-CB80-4671-9F92-90326411ACFC
```

Comment: thanks so much for the prompt response, Do you know how i can use python code in html like the python code above in xml

Comment: @EchiyeForcde I am not sure I understand your request.